# Apple script to move files of a type

Tags: macos-catalina

I have a folder of approximately 1800~ .7z files. Some of them uncompress as a single file, some uncompress as a folder with several of the same type of file. If I were to uncompress all of them at the same time, what I end up with is a folder full of .7z files, folders containing multiple of a file type, and multiple single instances of that same file type.

What I would like to do is run a script that would take all of the same file types, from all containing folders below the main folder, and copy them to another specified folder. I unfortunately don't have really any experience with Apple Scripts and while this may be simple, it sounds insurmountable to me. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey LCGhost, welcome to SO! What have _you tried_ so far? Try reading up [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/mv.html) and browsing some [Python](https://www.python.org/) documentation. Should help to get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Your question might get better answers over at https://apple.stackexchange.com